# Variable in IMG

Tags: javascript, html

So I am trying to incorporate a variable in my IMG tag, to basically replace a section with a username. On logon success I want it to get the Username of the user that was authenticated successfully, and replace that username in the variable. I am using javascript and html. Any ideas on hot I can achieve this? If I manually set the img src to a jpg, it shows and the rest of my code works as expected. I just need it it to show the pic depending on the username.

```js
$('form').submit(function () {
    var username = $('#username').val(),
    password = $('#password').val();

    clearMessage();

    if (!username || !password) {
      showMessage('Enter a username and a password');
      return false;
    }


    // Web Proxy request to log the user on
    ajaxWrapper({
      url: 'PostCredentialsAuth/Login',
      dataType: 'xml',
      success: loginSuccess,
      error: loginError,
      data: { username: username, password: password }
    });

function loginSuccess(data) {
        var $loginXml = $(data),
            result = $loginXml.find('Result').text();

        if (result == 'success') {
            $('form').hide();
            $('#log-off').show();
   $('#EmployeePic').show();
```

```html
    <img id="EmployeePic" src="'EmployeePhotos/'+Username+'.jpg'" alt="EmployeePic" class="EmployeePic" height="96" width="96" >
```

Comment: How about `$('#EmployeePic').attr('src', 'EmployeePhotos/'+username+'.jpg');`?

Comment: And what would I set for HTML piece?     <img id="EmployeePic" src="'EmployeePhotos/'+Username+'.jpg'" alt="EmployeePic" class="EmployeePic" height="96" width="96" >

Comment: A default image that will be replaced with the user image, maybe. Depends on you. You could also hide the image until the user is logged in.

Comment: Muecas, tried that and that did not work. I currently do have it set to show the image on success. That what the last 4 lines of code do.

Comment: You have to hide it first, so you can display it later. Check my answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could hide your image initially (i added some inline styles, but you can also do it using jQuery: `$('#EmployeePic').hide();`. Then when the user is logged in, the image source changes to `username.jpg` and the image is displayed.

```js
$('form').submit(function () {
    var username = $('#username').val(),
    password = $('#password').val();

    clearMessage();

    if (!username || !password) {
        showMessage('Enter a username and a password');
        return false;
    }


    // Web Proxy request to log the user on
    ajaxWrapper({
        url: 'PostCredentialsAuth/Login',
        dataType: 'xml',
        success: loginSuccess,
        error: loginError,
        data: { username: username, password: password }
    });

    function loginSuccess(data) {
        var $loginXml = $(data),
            result = $loginXml.find('Result').text();

        if (result == 'success') {
            $('form').hide();
            $('#log-off').show();
            $('#EmployeePic').error(function() {
                $(this).attr('src', 'EmployeePhotos/Default.jpg'); 
            }).attr('src', 'EmployeePhotos/'+$('#username').val()+'.jpg').show();
        }
    }
    
});
```

```html
<img id="EmployeePic" src="" alt="EmployeePic" class="EmployeePic" height="96" width="96" style="display: none;">
```

Comment: So it is almost working. Everything works good except it is not getting the username from the form submitted. If I change it to $('#EmployeePic').attr('src', 'EmployeePhotos/username.jpg').show(); it will show the file that I specify. As soon as I try and let it pull the username form the form it does not pull it.

Comment: That's strange. The variable `username` is in the same scope as the `loginSuccess` function (at least in your example). I changed it so it is always pulled from the form input. Let me know if it worked.

Comment: Also, check your console, to see if the image assigned exists in your project files.

Comment: That worked! Thanks a lot muecas! As a side question. I have all the pics currently on a different file server that is not here. For testing I created the EmployeePhotos folder to get this to work. Is it possible to have the location pull from a share like \\share\employeephotos?

Comment: I think it will be better to access those files from a webserver (could be a webserver in your own network). To pull the images from that location, any computer will need rights to access the folder and files under the server. Glad i cold help. Please mark the answer as correct if it solved your problem. Thanks!

Comment: Ok, I can just set up a script to mirror the folder to where I have it no. One last thing if the user does not have a file in that folder is there a way to default it to a standard jpb, like Default.jpg if there is not a username.jpg?

Comment: In case you wan to test, just change the script that changes the source of the image to: `$('#EmployeePic').attr('src', '\\share\employeephotos\'+$('#username').val()+'.jpg').show();`.

Comment: That worked! Thanks again. You are amazing. Just learning how to code and you have helped me tremendously.